# OVHCloud Fresh VPS Debian 10+Plesk, Wordpress WP Toolkit - General error 11 database disk image is malformed Pdo.php

Tags: debian, vps, plesk, zend-db, wptoolkit

I will keep this simple, after purchasing a fresh VPS with Debian 10 and Plesk Pro Edition pre-installed - In PLESK the Wordpress WP Toolkit module shows this error:

Server Error
500 Zend_Db_Statement_Exception
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 11 database disk image is malformed

Type    Zend_Db_Statement_Exception
Message    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 11 database disk image is malformed
File    Pdo.php
Line    61

Plesk Screenshots:
Wordpress Module: https://prnt.sc/Vk93iR4cGxl-
Error: https://prnt.sc/puGtrxQinLUp

I assume there has been an error in creation of the installation - no replies in an OVHCloud support ticket, maybe I can fix it if I have direction from someone here perhaps? Thanks.

Tried reinstalling etc, repairing but the error keeps returning.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same problem and fixed it by reinstalling Wordpress Toolkit.

Go to "Extensions" => "My Extensions" then click on "WordPress Toolkit" (not the "Open" button). At this step you should be on this url "/modules/catalog/index.php/installed/wp-toolkit".

Click the trash bin button to "Remove this extension." and go back to "Extensions" to reinstall it :)

Answer (score 0):

The "Database disk image is malformed" message in connection with WP Toolkit points to a corrupted SQLite3 database. Plesk's WP Toolkit is using that to store its own configuration values. The error ist most likely not caused by Plesk, because it has not really anything to do with storage content, but with the file on disk. Instead it suggest a corrupted file system or similar issues on the server. That is also the reason why deleting and reinstalling the Toolkit helps (because then that database file gets re-created, too).